# SSIS hidden sheets as Excel Destination

Tags: sql, ssis, excel, business-intelligence, vba

As occurring more often something simple is not so simple in SSIS (v 2008)

Situation **before** B.I. came in: data was loaded into linked tables in hidden excel sheets, there were macro's and manual adaptations.

**After**: Still hidden sheets but we replaced macro functionalities with SSIS and had to unlink the table to get rid of the pop-up when opening the files: "The following data may have been lost: -Table"

Since we unlinked the table (and by consequence deleted the connection) we can't address the hidden sheet anymore via SSIS: Excel Destination. Non-hidden sheets are no problem and are visible.

--> **Question**: how can you export to a hidden excel sheet? 
Since above action the sheet is not visible anymore in the Excel Destination windows, dropbox "name of the excel sheet".

Thanks in advance for any advice!!
L

Comment: Please review your previous questions and either accept answers or provide feedback on the supplied answers. People are happy to help but they enjoy the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) that comes with solving problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick when the GUI doesn't let you do something in SSIS is to tell it you know what you are doing. ;)

In this case, the drop down does not allow you to select values from a hidden tab. The connection manager points to a Excel file with 2 tabs, Sheet1 and Hidden which is hidden.
[image: Excel Destination table or view]

It does however allow you to select "Table name or view name from variable" or "SQL Command." This solution will use the variable approach but command should work just as well.
[image: Excel Destination table or view from variable]

As you can see, I have defined a variables called SheetName and assigned it a value of Hidden$
[image: Variable declaration]

Sample data flow

[image: Data flow]

Results

```
Progress: 2011-11-07 07:49:32.80
   Source: Excel Destination
   Cleanup: 100% complete
End Progress
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  7:49:30 AM
Finished: 7:49:32 AM
Elapsed:  2.121 seconds
```