# Importing sql table data to excel sheet by adding a new sheet to existing excel file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a ssis package which calls stored procudere and fill data in a table say table1.
I have a excel file at shared location which already contains 2 sheets and necessary information on these sheets.I have to add another sheet in the existing excel file with the data of table1 copied into it through ssis/sql.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your existing package by adding a Data Flow after the Execute SQL Task. The Data Flow task would most likely contain an OLE DB source with a query like `SELECT * FROM table1`  You might need a type conversion task attached to that to make the data into unicode, can't say for certain based on the paucity of details. Wire that into an Excel Destination. I answered an earlier question on writing to [hidden Excel Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036391/ssis-hidden-sheets-as-excel-destination/8037246#8037246) which might provide some insight on using Excel in SSIS.